# taking file content as file name itself in tcl

Tags: tcl

I am running one tcl script who is taking file as a input by  "stdin".The problem is that its taking the file content as a filename and throwing error while running the script on command line processor.

tcl script is

```
#!/bin/sh
# SystemInfo_2.tcl \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}


set traps [read stdin];
#set traps "snmp trap test"
set timetrap [clock format [clock seconds]];

set trapout [open Database_traps_event.txt a+];
set javaout [open JavaTrapOutput.txt a+];
puts $trapout $timetrap;
puts $trapout $traps;
puts $trapout "Before executing java program";
set javaprogargs "open {|java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar;.  EventAlarmHandling \"$traps\"} r";
puts $trapout $javaprogargs;
set javaprogram [eval $javaprogargs];
puts $trapout "Execution of java is over"
while { [gets $javaprogram line] != -1 } {
    puts $javaout $line; 
    }
close $javaprogram;


puts $trapout "After excution of java program\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
close $trapout;
close $javaout; 
exit;
```

input file content is -

```
<UNKNOWN>
UDP: [192.168.1.19]:60572->[0.0.0.0]:0
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysUpTime.sysUpTimeInstance 1:9:58:56.61
.iso.org.dod.internet.snmpV2.snmpModules.snmpMIB.snmpMIBObjects.snmpTrap.snmpTrapOID.0 .iso.org.dod.internet.snmpV2.snmpModules.snmpMIB.snmpMIBObjects.snmpTraps.linkDown
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifIndex.1 8
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifAdminStatus.8 up
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifOperStatus.8 down
```

From command line it ran like below

```
E:\eventAlarmHandling>tclsh TclTempFile.tcl < traps.txt
couldn't read file "UNKNOWN>
UDP: [192.168.1.19]:60572->[0.0.0.0]:0
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysUpTime.sysUpTimeInstance 1:9:58:56.61
.iso.org.dod.internet.snmpV2.snmpModules.snmpMIB.snmpMIBObjects.snmpTrap.snmpTrapOID.0 .iso.org.dod.intern
et.snmpV2.snmpModules.snmpMIB.snmpMIBObjects.snmpTraps.linkDown
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifIndex.1 8
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifAdminStatus.8 up
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifOperStatus.8 down": No error
    while executing
"open {|java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar;.  EventAlarmHandling "<UNKNOWN>
UDP: [192.168.1.19]:60572->[0.0.0.0]:0
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib..."
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $javaprogargs"
    invoked from within
"set javaprogram [eval $javaprogargs]"
    (file "TclTempFile.tcl" line 26)
```

So clearly in command line its showing that "couldn't read file UNKNOWN> ......"
So please explain it that whats happening here in command line.I am new to tcl.So hoping that someone help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having problems with one of the trickier bits of how pipelines work in Tcl. If we look at the [documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm#M21) *carefully*, we see:

> If the first character of *fileName* is “`|`” then the remaining characters of *fileName* are treated as a list of arguments that describe a command pipeline to invoke, in the same style as the arguments for `exec`.

That means you have to have the first character be `|` and the rest, after stripping that first character, be a proper list. In your case, you've not got that. Instead, you're doing:

```
set javaprogargs "open {|java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar;.  EventAlarmHandling \"$traps\"} r";
```

That's pretty complicated anyway. Let's build this in the idiomatic fashion instead:

```
set CPsep ";"
set classpath [list mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar .]
set javaprogargs [list open |[list \
        java -cp [join $classpath $CPsep] EventAlarmHandling $traps]]
```

It helps to split the classpath out; it's got a `;` character in it (on Windows; you'll need to change that if you port to Linux or OSX) and it's nicer to use `list` in Tcl to build things and then `join` to convert into what Java expects.

We also no longer need any backslash-quoted substrings in there (except the one I put in to keep lines short and readable); the pattern of `list` commands there will add everything that is required. Note the `|[list …]` there: that's non-idiomatic everywhere in Tcl *except when creating a pipeline* when it is recommended practice as it is doing in reverse what `open` expects to parse.

---

The other thing you're running into is [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm#M10):

> If an *arg* (or pair of *arg*s) has one of the forms described below then it is used by `exec` to control the flow of input and output among the subprocess(es). Such arguments will not be passed to the subprocess(es).
>
> <sup>[…]</sup>
> `<` *fileName*
> The file named by *fileName* is opened and used as the standard input for the first command in the pipeline.

Your argument from `$traps` starts with a `<` and so it triggers this rule.

Unfortunately, there's ***no*** simple workaround for this and this is a severe, known, and very annoying limitation of the pipeline creation code. The only known techniques for dealing with this are to move to transferring that data by either a file or via the subprocess's standard input, both of which require modifying the subprocess's implementation. If you can make that Java program read from `System.in` (a good idea anyway, so you don't hit Windows's command line length limitations!) then you can pass the value like this:

```
set CPsep ";"
set classpath [list mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar .]
set javaprogargs [list open |[list \
        java -cp [join $classpath $CPsep] EventAlarmHandling << $traps]]
```

That is just by adding a `<<` in there immediately before the value.

Comment: Hi @Donal thanks for your input . I have made changes but result  is same no success. When I changed the content of input  file as "Welcome!!" , It ran fine without any error. But when the content of input file is "<UNKNOWN>
......."(same as in question) .   Its throwing the same error as specified in question above

Comment: Read the second half of my answer.

Comment: Yeah I have read that also but after I have made changes  now its throwing **"
E:\eventAlarmHandling>tclsh TclTempFile.tcl < traps.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at EventAlarmHandling.main(EventAlarmHandling.java:1716)
    while executing
"close $javaprogram"
    (file "TclTempFile.tcl" line 30) " **.Clearly exception got  throws  by java class because java class is not able to recognizing the command line argument.